# Does std::atomic access serve as a memory barrier?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Can the compiler reorder instructions on atomics, or do atomics serve as a memory barrier? 
Put again, can instructions written after an atomic instruction execute before the atomic instruction?

See the following code. If `useMapA = false` is moved before `mapB` is updated and the reading thread begins, we will use an invalid `mapB`.

Note: the update thread only happens once every 15 minutes, so we have a very well structured flow, and a way to avoid using an expensive lock call!

```
std::atomic<bool> useMapA;
std::map<string, string> mapA, mapB;

public void updateMap(map<string, string>* latestMap) {
    if (useMapA) {
        mapB = std::move(*latestMap);
        useMapA = false;
    } else {
        mapA = std::move(*latestMap);
        useMapA = true;
    }
}

inline map<string, string>& getMap() {
    return useMapA ? mapA : mapB;
}
```

Edit: I am interested in trading away being 100% thread-safe for speed (time = money). This read function needs to run really fast. You can assume that 15 minutes is long enough to avoid race conditions that would be caused if this time was much shorter.

Comment: Have you read the standard about std::memory_order, regarding atomic operations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before answering your question, I would like to show, how you can easily implement the feature with **std::shared_ptr** and *atomic operations*. The following implementation is efficient and thread-safe. There is also no need for the *readers* to create a copy of the map.

```
using string_map = std::map<std::string, std::string>;

std::shared_ptr<const string_map> map;

std::shared_ptr<const string_map> getMap()
{
    return std::atomic_load(&map);
}

void updateMap(string_map latestMap)
{
    std::shared_ptr<const string_map> temp{
        new string_map{std::move(latestMap)}};
    std::atomic_store(&map, temp);
}
```

Now, let's take a look at your code. It's a bit more complicated. To make it easier, let's assume that *updateMap* is called every second instead of every 15 minutes. *useMapA* is initially *true*. The update thread executes the following statements and will be interrupted before updating the atomic flag:

```
if (useMapA) {
    mapB = std::move(*latestMap);
```

Now, a reader thread only evaluates the atomic flag:

```
bool r1 = useMapA; // r1==true
```

The update thread is continued and sets the atomic flag to *false*. A second later, the update thread evaluates the atomic flag:

```
if (useMapA) { // condition is false
```

Now, the reader thread is continued. Both threads access *mapA*, and at least one thread writes to the data structure. That means, there is a *data race*, and that means the behavior of the program is undefined, regardless whether this *data race* really occurs.

What changes if the *updateMap* is called only every 15 minutes? Unless there happens some additional synchronization within this 15 minutes, it is still a data race, because the *C++ Standard* doesn't make a difference between a second and 15 minutes.

Comment: Edited the original post, the map copy is avoided by returning a map& instead of a map. Your solution with shared_ptrs is indeed better than the original implementation, thank you!